# How to make LAMP server accessible from the internet?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, lamp

I want to make my own SNS (Social Networking Site), so I installed LAMP on my Ubuntu 14.04. But its not accessible from the internet! I can run the server only on my computer by typing https://localhost on my browser.

I don't want any domains; I just want that whosoever from any part of the world wants to use my SNS he/she just have to type the ip-address and my SNS opens i.e. I want my server accessible from the internet.

My router is Binatone DT 850W. Can you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** If it works on your localhost, Ubuntu is ready and we cannot help you any further as this now became a router and ISP issue. However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they ***might*** be able to help you with your router. Alternatively, download the manual for your router and look for ”DMZ”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ubuntu works perfectly fine. You have to set up your router, so first of all read about Port Forwarding. Then you have to give your computer a static ip inside your home network. You can define it from your router. When you do this steps , the user will enter your public ip of your router and can see your site. The problem is that your public ip is not static , it may change everytime your home internet is rebooted. Also it is not secure because if someone had access to your laptop outside your hoek network they can have access to all your devices through security holes.

To learn how to set up your route, you should ask the routers site of stackexchange as proposed in the comment.

P.s. you can use something like Heroku, if you only want to show your site for free to someone. But for production in Heroku you have to pay.